# Command to refresh binary paths in CentOS?

Tags: centos, path, binary

This is probably really easy and I just can't seem to find it.

I'm moving binaries around between /usr/bin and /usr/sbin, and even though both folders are in my $PATH, moving one binary to the other causes the system to continuously look for it in its original place.

Anyone know why this is, and if there is a command to refresh it?

Comment: have you tried the rehash command ?

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bash - the answer is below, the "hash -r" command.  I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For bash

```
hash -r
```

should cause the shell to forget about the remembered locations.

Comment: Oh my god I knew it was easy.  I've never heard of the hash command - thank you JasonAzze!